# SOAPUI Error : java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream

Tags: wsdl, soapui

Am trying to view a wsdl file from SOAPUI but it throws the following error. I have researched the internet for a way to fix this but to no avail. What could be the issue here?

`Error loading [http://XX.X.X.X:XXXX/XXXXXXXXX?xsd=xsd0]: java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream`

Comment: Ever have any luck figuring out what your issue was on this?

Comment: @TimKelly i figured out that the port from which the webservice was hosted was not open. I was able to access the wsdl file after the allowing traffic to the specific port from the firewall and the server.

Answer (score 5):

The following was the solution for me:

Instead of
XXXXX?wsdl
try
XXXXX?singleWsdl

Comment: +1. Even though I add saved the wsdl and replaced all references to "http://localhost/xxx" with real and working URLs, I still got that message (still referencing "localhost"). After retrieving the wsdl from "?singleWsdl": no more errors 