# IOException: Attempted read from closed stream in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I have problem with one of my endpoint in my SoapUI project. Every REST API Endpoints works fine, I have null pointer only when I tried used this one:
Error log:

```
Thu Jul 13 12:27:14 CEST 2017:ERROR:java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.
   java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:166)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toByteArray(EntityUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity.<init>(BufferedHttpEntity.java:60)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpMethodSupport.getResponseBody(HttpMethodSupport.java:237)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.support.methods.ExtendedPostMethod.getResponseBody(ExtendedPostMethod.java:116)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.SinglePartHttpResponse.<init>(SinglePartHttpResponse.java:51)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.HttpPackagingResponseFilter.httpRequest(HttpPackagingResponseFilter.java:80)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.HttpPackagingResponseFilter.afterAbstractHttpResponse(HttpPackagingResponseFilter.java:51)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.afterRequest(AbstractRequestFilter.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:272)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Thu Jul 13 12:27:14 CEST 2017:ERROR:java.lang.NullPointerException
   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.followRedirects(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:327)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:242)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I receive also blank page in GUI. What's weird in httplog in SoapUI shows proper response:

```
Thu Jul 13 12:27:14 CEST 2017:DEBUG:>> "POST /restAPI/unique/prepResult/1425841400000/1499855809035Id=58fa1ed8d HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 13 12:27:14 CEST 2017:DEBUG:>> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 13 12:27:14 CEST 2017:DEBUG:>> "Authentication: EI48Q0OEfVa4TeCpgbWZ7z65X_9KtrXysQJKF6C9WIoLxtgeWcaBx9n6HOqVl2689ZOXwkgwIfGGyJkGu2CkpjuDO5n2-IVPIiJ1_w7PufvPWroZoPG1rsmoIe1RW81QsV0Pqpq6NOe-Qmd4DP2GZt6kmGNQA4DKEKaW61h-skYPQ3tuBSvL0G_GDYPcTOCX6r9rLN8qX7NH8FI3E4JEwQOFWEUi5JBH19yR_o4-sBHD8cWNRmgQ2tch7pqTg1ECNFoS1gXS5bKuhbvY03hP2BiZlC7dzRhOdEUmvINw0LXK36p096ly4vWimoKjZlxV3tlFtvgJ5x1OyyGkx4kL6wewDgmY4POe6VA6K[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 13 12:27:14 CEST 2017:DEBUG:>> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 13 12:27:14 CEST 2017:DEBUG:>> "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 13 12:27:14 CEST 2017:DEBUG:>> "Host: localhost[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 13 12:27:14 CEST 2017:DEBUG:>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 13 12:27:14 CEST 2017:DEBUG:>> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 13 12:27:14 CEST 2017:DEBUG:>> "[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 13 12:27:14 CEST 2017:DEBUG:<< "HTTP/1.1 302 Found[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 13 12:27:14 CEST 2017:DEBUG:<< "Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 10:27:14 GMT[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 13 12:27:14 CEST 2017:DEBUG:<< "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 13 12:27:14 CEST 2017:DEBUG:<< "Content-Length: 51[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 13 12:27:14 CEST 2017:DEBUG:<< "[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 13 12:27:14 CEST 2017:DEBUG:<< "{"result":"51934ad95949"}"
```

At the end in httplog i receive proper result in json

Comment: I highly suggest you delete the authentication line from your response. Bad idea to post auth information online. My guess is that the 302 (redirect) might be part of the cause. Also if this service requires a certain port to be open, that could also be a cause https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33501762/soapui-error-java-io-ioexception-attempted-read-from-closed-stream

Comment: Thank You, no worries I have changed whole endpoints,hosts and auth header before posting this thread. I will check redirection part, there was something done last time with http > https redirections.